# Insert AdSense WordPress Loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to insert AdSense Code inside my wordpress loop after 3, 5, 10 posts. this is my code:

```
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

        get_template_part('/framework/templates/content-grid', get_post_format());

    endwhile;

    else :

        get_template_part( '/framework/templates/content', 'none' );

endif; ?>
```

How could I manage this?

Comment: Please try to use brackets to avoid confusions and to make your code more readable. It might be a little in this case, but its a huge different on larger scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can achieve this by creating a custom counter.

     <?php
    $i = 1;
       if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php
                    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

     if($i==3||$i==5||$i==10){
        /*Adsence here*/
        }
             get_template_part( '/framework/templates/content-grid', get_post_format() );

       $i++;
             endwhile;

          else :

            get_template_part( '/framework/templates/content', 'none' );

                endif; ?>
```